# regex: every dot in string has at least one preceding letter

Tags: regex

I have the following regex situation:
The string is a certain combination of letters, numbers and dots. However, the string should only be matched, if every dot that occurs has at least one preceeding letter.
The following examples have to be valid:

```
123f.12ed.ad2d
1s.2s.2d.3wd.fw.e.ss.asda
12312vsd
dss.
```

These should be invalid:

```
as2.
..ad2
2.12as.
.ad2ads
```

I've tried using lookbehind, but it doesn't work the way I need it to. It validates string that should not be valid.

```
^[a-z0-9\.]*(?<=[a-z])\.*$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex will permit dots anywhere. You need to constrain them.

```
^[a-z0-9]*([a-z]\.[a-z0-9]*)*$
```

So, anything without a dot is fine. Then there must be at least one alphabetic followed by a dot, and then basically repeat the same pattern any number of times.

The "a*(ba*)*" high-level pattern is typical for "a* with optional b:s embedded" (or you can turn it around and say "(a*b)*a*").

Your attempt would allow anything, then trailing dots after a single alphabetic; but it looks like you misunderstand the lookbehind. There is no real need for that here anyway.

Perhaps a regex visualizer with "railroad" graphics could help you grasp regexes. Try https://www.debuggex.com/r/hnpp_ev2utNlZbQC for instance.

Comment: I'm still having trouble to grasp the whole idea of lookbehind. Your solution works perfectly fine though - thanks for the great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

This lookbehind based regex should work:

```
^(?:[^.]*(?<=[a-zA-Z])\.)*[^.]*$
```

Or else

```
^(?:[A-Za-z0-9]*(?<=[a-zA-Z])\.)*[A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qU0hP2/1)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to test if the string *has* a dot not preceded by a letter to exclude it:

```
[^a-z]\.|\A\.
```

The string is valid if the pattern fails.